# in app purchase - SKProduct Request Fail

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

i am implementing this code :

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
    // Display a store to the user.
    NSLog(@"Device Can Make Payments");
    SKProductsRequest *ProductRequst = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"slalomtfcoins", nil]];
    ProductRequst.delegate = self;
    [ProductRequst start];
}
else {
    // Warn the user that purchases are disabled.
    NSLog(@"Device Can't Make Payments");
    UIAlertView *thealert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Your Device Limited" message:@"we have noticed that you device restrictions setting are currently limited. you can change it ny going to Settings -> General -> Restrictions and turn it off" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [thealert show];
    [thealert release];
}



-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
SKProduct *VailProduct = nil;
NSLog(@"%d",[response.products count]);
int count = [response.products count];
if (count>0) {
    VailProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Products are availble");
} else if (!VailProduct){
    NSLog(@"Products are Not availble");
}
```

}

and the log prints "Products are Not availble".
the bundle id in my p.list are correct
and the product id is the same as the itunes connect.

what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: If you have just created the products in iTunes connect sometimes it takes a while (couple of hours or more) before you can test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try.

- delete then redownload the provisioning profiles in xcode and the
  device
- delete the app from the device
- log out of the store
- List item
- hard reboot your device
- Build and run the app
- try again

Another fix that I discovered that probably wont help but you may try is to create a new test account user and try that one. Since your issue is simply validating, not purchasing, that probably wont help. I just mention it in case you have problems down the road too.

Also if this is the first time doing this you should double check the app id and product ids just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

are you running the app from xcode?, if you are using the "enviroment-sandbox" for unreleased apps that use in-app purchase, you have to run it from xcode for use the "enviroment-sandbox"

Answer (score 1):

If your device is not in the US store there seems to be a bug in the sandbox that can be fixed by going to iTunes in the device and switching stores. When you attempt the purchase again in your app it should prompt to change back to the other store.

Also make sure you're testing on a device and not on the simulator and that you use a test account that you created through iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

On xCode 4.5.1 I'm sure (because I try) you can use the iPhone Simulator for all In-App Purchase process. 
It's only a little slow and sometimes go in time-out, so you have to retry to buy or restart the simulation (in Simulator and in iPhone).
 
In code, you can setup a Bool and assign TRUE to it after the successful purchase process. Use an NSLog to be sure all things goes fine.
After that you can use that bool for all your needs.

Another thing: you have to be sure the product identifier is fully correct, for example:
com.example.myapp.purchase1
com.example.myapp.purchase2
...
Put these values in iTunes Connect and in your app.

Maybe you have to wait just a little time for iTunes update (for me, I don't know why, the time to wait is really short: just a couple of minutes or even less)